# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string. Выбрасывает исклчение при тестировании юнит тестом и мокито

Tags: java, исключения, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

Для начала покажу вам методы которые я хочу протестировать, это AzureService

```
@Service
public class AzureCloudStorageService implements FileService {
    private final String connectionString;
    private final String containerName;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public AzureCloudStorageService(@Autowired PropertyResolver propertyResolver,
        ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.connectionString = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.connection.string");
        this.containerName = propertyResolver.getProperty("azure.container.name");
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
    public String upload(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        final String blob = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        BlobClient client = containerClient()
            .getBlobClient(blob + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            client.upload(new BufferedInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream()), multipartFile.getSize());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new NotSavedException(ErrorMessage.FILE_NOT_SAVED);
        }
        return client.getBlobUrl();
    }

    private BlobContainerClient containerClient() {
        BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
        return serviceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    }
```

Сейчас покажу мою попытку затестировать это, так как тут не нужно ничего особеного мокать, я думал что если вызвать и сравнить сам метод, то все отлично заработает. В коментариях это то что я думал, что надо создать, но думаю оно не нужно

```
@Test
    void upload() {
//        azureCloudStorageService.upload(multipartFile);
//        String blob = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
//        BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
//                .connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
//        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient1 = serviceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
//        BlobClient client = blobContainerClient1
//                .getBlobClient(blob + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        String expected = "image";
        MultipartFile multipartFile = ModelUtils.getFile();
        String actual = azureCloudStorageService.upload(multipartFile);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Ну и сам уже Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connection string.

    at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.connectionstring.StorageConnectionString.create(StorageConnectionString.java:103)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.connectionString(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:240)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageService.containerClient(AzureCloudStorageService.java:54)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageService.upload(AzureCloudStorageService.java:42)
    at greencity.service.AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.upload(AzureCloudStorageServiceTest.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Comment: Хотя это и довольно распространенная практика (писать тест на метод мокая зависимости), в таких тестах (особенно для компонентов интеграции с внешними системами) обычно мало смысла (сильная зависимость от реализации и хрупкость теста). Лучше написать интеграционный тест на поведение, т.е. такой тест, который будет 1. действительно сохранять данные в хранилище 2. и потом читать их из хранилища используя другой метод из AzureCloudStorageService (вероятно, там есть метод для получения файла типа `get`) 3. проверять, что то что прочитали соответствует тому, что записали.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/ . Особенно вопросу релевантны разделы про юнит и интеграционные тесты.